# Compare two sentences on basis of grammar using NLP

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I have 2 sentences to compare on the basis of their grammar using NLP. I am completely new to NLP and want to know if there is an algorithm to determine this. I know how to compare using word similarity and sentiments.

Comment: "compare on the basis of their grammar"

can you elaborate a bit more on this? maybe with an example?

Comment: Assume I have the sentences: "I like hot dogs" and "My father's favourite food is hot dog". Now I want to compare these two sentences that how similar they are in terms of their Grammar by using NLP.

Comment: it's still not clear to me what do you want exactly, compare how many common verbs they have? or common adjectives? or dependency parsing structure, how common the structure is?

Comment: I didn't think about structures but now that you said about the structure i will be trying that out. Any help from you will be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nltk wordnet's synsets to measure the similarity between two sentences

here is how to generate all possible synsets without having to specify the grammar, you can later choose which synsets to use based on a certain criterion

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import itertools

#use stemmer 
stm = PorterStemmer()
sent1 =  "I like hot dogs"
sent2 = "My father's favourite food is hot dog"
#Convert the tag given by nltk.pos_tag to the tag used by wordnet.synsets
tag_dict = {'N': 'n', 'J': 'a', 'R': 'r', 'V': 'v'}

s1 = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent1))

s1 = dict(filter(lambda x: len(x[1])>0,
                 map(lambda row: (row[0],wn.synsets(
                       stm.stem(row[0]),
                       tag_dict[row[1][0]])) if row[1][0] in tag_dict.keys() 
                     else (row[0],[]),s1)))

s2 = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent2))

s2 = dict(filter(lambda x: len(x[1])>0,
                 map(lambda row: (row[0],wn.synsets(
                          stm.stem(row[0]),
                          tag_dict[row[1][0]])) if row[1][0] in tag_dict.keys() 
                     else (row[0],[]),s2)))
```

Here is a sample of the values in the dictionary s1

```
dogs    [Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n...
hot     [Synset('hot.a.01'), Synset('hot.s.02'), Synset('hot.a.03'), Synset('hot.s.0...
like    [Synset('wish.v.02'), Synset('like.v.02'), Synset('like.v.03'), Synset('like...
```

Here is one way. here I measure similarity between all possible synsets of two words then take the max.

```
res = {}
for w2,gr2 in s2.items():
    for w1,gr1 in s1.items():
        tmp = pd.Series(list(map(lambda row: row[1].path_similarity(row[0]),
                                 itertools.product(gr1,gr2)))).dropna()
        if len(tmp)>0:
            res[(w1,w2)] = tmp.max()
print(res)
```

Output

```
{('dogs', 'dog'): 1.0,
 ('dogs', 'father'): 0.16666666666666666,
 ('dogs', 'food'): 0.25,
 ('dogs', 'is'): 0.10000000000000001,
 ('hot', 'hot'): 1.0,
 ('hot', 'is'): 0.33333333333333331,
 ('like', 'is'): 0.33333333333333331}
```

Now we find the max similarity each word in a sentence achieve. then take the mean

```
similarity = pd.Series(res).groupby(level=0).max().mean()
print(similarity)
```

the output is `.778`

The above is the common approach when measuring document similarity. if you're looking to compare the grammar, you may want to use A part-of-speech tagger like pos_tag (or using a tagged corpus like `nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words()`) on both sentences then find the Jaccard distance between the tags.

Comment: Sorry for replying this late and Thank you!   This is something which i needed. I used synsets before but for comparing individual words, didn't know how to use synsets for comparing sentences.